# Get Django download attachment from web-browser

Tags: javascript, django, browser, attachment

I want to send image as attachment.

My code:

```
resp = FileResponse(open(fullImgPath, "rb"))
resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(fullImgPath))
resp["Content-Type"]="image/%s"%('png' if fullImgPath.endswith('png') else 'jpeg')
return resp
```

It does work, if i download file via `requests`. But when i download file via browser (chrome and firefox), file is corrupted .

How i do it via browser (javascript):

```
$.get(requestUrl)
        .success(function(data, textStatus, request){
                SaveBlob(data, "1,jpeg", "image/jpeg")
            }
        })

function SaveBlob(blob, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { "type" : contentType }));
    a.download = fileName;
    a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
}
```

It worked before! Today i found file i get is corrupted. However, file stored at server is normal image.

What's wrong?

Comment: You have syntax errors in js. `.success` is deprecated - should use `.done`. Js is incomplete - no `getFname()`, `getCtype()` or `ParseRespHeaders()`. Apart from that, django side is fine.

Comment: that was my own functions, that returns string fileName and string Content-type from parsing headers. For test this can be used as SaveBlob(data, '1.jpeg', 'image/jpeg') . The working solution only open(requestUrl, '_blank') . Is saving blobs in ajax way possible in all without corrupting file?

Comment: if you fetch it using ajax, it seems to me you don't need to return it with Content-Disposition "attachment". Not sure if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery doesn't download content of file as binary, hence your image is corrupted. Looks like jquery doesn't support downloading as binary, but you can use native xhr:

```
function SaveBlob(blob, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], {"type": contentType}));
    a.download = fileName;
    a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    SaveBlob(oReq.response, '1.jpg', 'image/jpg')
};
oReq.send();
```

Wonder how it worked previously.